# What are some regular contests unpublished short story authors might enter?

Tags: short-story, contests

One good way for new authors to become recognized is a contest.  What contests exist that:

- Accept **short stories**
- Occur on a **regular** (annual, semi-annual, bi-annual, etc.) basis
- Are friendly to **unpublished** authors
- Ideally provide a good amount of **publicity** within the target market.

If the contest caters to a specific genre or has important entrance criteria, those would be helpful to note.

Comment: I think it would be wise to only add contests here that occur on a regular basis.  Answers with one-off contests will quickly become out of date.

Comment: @sjohnston: Agreed. @justkt: Thanks for making the question more precise.

Comment: Are there any other cyclical contests out there? Does having this question with a status of "answered" keep others from contributing?

Comment: One way to go about this is to look at the journals and collections in your genre. These usually include author notes that include the journals and contest they've won. Then investigate the ones that stories similar to yours have appeared in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Writers of the Future](http://www.writersofthefuture.com/) is for SF/F, but it's the longest-running contest in the genre, and carries significant fame and prestige. No other contest comes close. WotF is specifically for unpublished writers, and occurs once a quarter. Check the website for entrance dates and other information.

Comment: I was a little astonished to see L. Ron Hubbard all over the page, but right, he was also an author. The contest seems unrelated to Scientology.

Comment: Wow, the Jury is the Who is Who of SF.

Comment: They have four rounds each year. If you qualify you should try to have a story in each quarter.

Comment: Elron wrote SF, too.  The most well-known of his SF works is, in fact, Scientology.  (S,CRNR)

Comment: Actually, include me out of this contest.  I really wouldn't want to be associated with L. Ron Hubbard in *any* way, at all.  The WP article on the contest (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writers_of_the_Future) is worth reading.

Comment: Writers of the Future is outstanding, imo. They pay above industry-average rates for winners' stories included in the annual anthology, and unlike most competitions the author retains all publishing rights.

Answer (score 1):

Glimmer Train offers a few different types of short story contests regularly and one especially for new authors.

http://www.glimmertrain.com/writguid1.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search turned up this list of [19 short story competitions](http://www.aerogrammestudio.com/2014/11/27/19-short-story-competitions-2015/). 
Here's another list of [short story competitions, sorted by deadline](http://fictionwriting.about.com/od/thebusinessofwriting/a/contesthub.htm).