# What's a good resource to find Beta Readers for  short stories?

Tags: resources, beta-readers

I'm currently in the market for beta readers, particularly for short stories. I've finished an early draft for a contest, and I'm hoping to hear some feedback.  I'm open to reading the work of others as well. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet communities where I can read/rate/review short fiction, and post my own?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/internet-communities-where-i-can-read-rate-review-short-fiction-and-post-my-own)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [YouWriteOn](http://youwriteon.com/). Rather than me tell you how it works, this is from their [About Us](http://youwriteon.com/info/about-us.aspx) page:

> YouWriteOn began in 2006 to assist new writers to develop their writing. Editors for leading publishers such as Random House and Orion - who publish bestselling writers such as John Grisham, Bill Bryson and Ian Rankin - review our highest rated writers each month.
>
> YouWriteOn's premise is simple: members upload opening chapters or short stories and the YouWriteOn system randomly assigns these to another member to review. You then review another member's story excerpt - assigned to you at random - each time you want to receive a new review back in return. After 5 reviews a story enters our chart system and the highest rated writers receive free feedback each month from editors for leading publishers Orion and Random House.
>
> Feedback can be diverse, but the experience of the site over its history has been that collective feedback from a range of reviewers helps writers to get a collective viewpoint of what works well and what needs developing in their stories. The result has been that the majority of stories are higher rated as a result of revising their writing through feedback.

Comment: Thank you Craig, it sounds like a good idea. My hope is to gain some immediate feedback, and this seems like it will be useful to that end. It's so difficult to get feedback unless you've become well established in an online community. That's fine, except the deadline is a week away. Thanks again for offering your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Critique Circle is a good source. You can easily find people who will read your work and give you feedback and suggestions.

http://www.critiquecircle.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Scribophile at http://www.scribophile.com. The premise is that folks earn points by critiquing and spend points to put their work up for critique. The system means that no one hogs the spotlight without helping other folks. You're pretty much guaranteed 3 critiques.