# Site for free author reviews

Tags: reviews

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/904/what-are-good-places-to-post-your-work-where-it-will-be-read-by-others)

What are some good sites to have your written works reviewed? I'm not necessarily talking about Profession Book Reviews, but a place where everyone can comment on the work and give their criticism? I'm just wanting it so I can improve upon my writing.