# where would be a good place to find writers for my staff?

Tags: creative-writing

I want a staff of 16 writers to work on a creative project. Are there websites where I can find good writers to do free work? Please post links. I'm not advertising here.

Comment: Check out this question: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/904/what-are-good-places-to-post-your-work-where-it-will-be-read-by-others Every place where writers gather would be good. May I ask what kind of work? Maybe some people around here would be interested.

Comment: "Staff" usually implies remuneration, but you also say "free work". Which is it?

Comment: Also, as the question is written, it reads to me more like a poll or list question than one that can be answered with a single authoritative answer, and thus would seem to be at risk of closing as "not constructive". Could you perhaps re-word it so that it can be more definitively answered? See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Writers.SE help center.

Comment: And why would "good writers" do "free work" for you?

Comment: Well it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Tannalein answered my question in the comments. Thank you!